# Cannot upload files with Azure Pipelines FTP

Tags: azure-devops, ftp, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to upload all .js files in a folder called dist to a FTP server. I'm able to upload entire folders and the files inside but am unable to upload any files outside of a folder.

```
- task: FtpUpload@2
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: 'inputs'
    serverUrl: 'FTPServerUrl'
    username: 'Username'
    password: 'Password'
    rootDirectory: './node_modules'
    filePatterns: '**'
    remoteDirectory: '/site/wwwroot/node_modules'
    clean: true
    cleanContents: true
    preservePaths: false
    trustSSL: false
```

This is what normally works for me. It just doesn't work with files. Only directories.

```
- task: FtpUpload@2
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: 'inputs'
    serverUrl: 'FTPServerUrl'
    username: 'Username'
    password: 'Password'
    rootDirectory: './dist'
    filePatterns: 'dist/*.js'
    remoteDirectory: '/site/wwwroot'
    clean: true
    cleanContents: true
    preservePaths: false
    trustSSL: false
```

This is what I've tried and I keep getting this type of error:

```
##[warning]Could not find any files to upload
```

Can somebody please help me understand the problem?

Comment: This does not look like a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'm sorry but can you clarify what you mean? The FtpUpload@2 task is something used inside a Yaml file. Yaml is recognized as a programing language according to Wikipedia. This question also involves Azure Devops which is a Software as a Service platform. I think a SAAS counts as a software tool. The link you showed says that questions can cover software tools used by programmers as long as it contains a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development. Does my problem lack that, do I need to be more specific about my desired result or did I do something else wrong?

Comment: could be because your already in the folder dist as you've set this as your root directory? may need to change the file pattern to '*.js'

Comment: TheWinterCoder is correct. The reason for my error was that I was already in the dist folder. Thank you for your help. It didn't work the first time I tried to fix the file patern and directory route, but that was because I also had to change the clean to false.